# Why am i getting empty matches with this pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, balanced-groups

On `http://regexstorm.net/tester` i use the following pattern:

```
(?:(?!\(|\)|\,).)*(?:(?:(?'open'\()(?:(?!\(|\)).)*)+((?'content-open'\))(?:(?!\(|\)|\,).)*)+)*(?(open)(?!))
```

And the following value:

```
(asi(de, fghdfh(fghjgh))),(dfgsdg)
rtyerty,
dhggjkmf,
bnmvbm,
cvbngfh,
iopuip
```

And every other match for me is empty. It works correctly if you switch the first `*` to a `+`, but i need it to be a `*`, because there doesn't have to be any characters before the balanced-group. I know that i can just ignore the empty matches, but it is kind of annoying to me and i am wondering if there may be something wrong with my pattern?

Is there a specific character or anchor that is getting matched that i can throw into a `[^...]` group to use instead of the initial `.`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you suffer from overlapping alternate matches:
I've tried to simplify the pattern. I am not fully there (and I hope I have not removed too much) but this should be already an improvement:

```
(?:[^(),])*(?:(?:(?<open>\()(?:[^()])*)+|((?<content-open>\))(?:[^(),])*))*
```

Either way, if your pattern does what you want stick with it.